# How to set params in Python requests library

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, python-requests

I have the following code using urllib in Python 2.7 and its working. I'm trying to do the same request using the requests library but I cant get it to work.

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import json

req = urllib2.Request(url='https://testone.limequery.com/index.php/admin/remotecontrol',\
                          data='{\"method\":\"get_session_key\",\"params\":[\"username\",\"password\"],\"id\":1}')
req.add_header('content-type', 'application/json')
req.add_header('connection', 'Keep-Alive')

f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
myretun = f.read()

j=json.loads(myretun)
print(j['result'])
```

Using requests library( Doesn't work)

```
import requests
import json

d= {"method":"get_session_key","params":["username","password"],"id":"1"}


headers = {'content-type' :'application/json','connection': 'Keep-Alive'}
req2 = requests.get(url='https://testone.limequery.com/index.php/admin/remotecontrol',data=d,headers=headers)

json_data = json.loads(req2.text)
print(json data['result'])
```

I'm getting an error `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` How can I make the code work with the requests library?

Comment: A GET request with JSON data?

Comment: @KlausD. Oh I'll edit my question now thanks

Comment: @KlausD. I have it now as a dictionary but still doesnt work

Comment: What actually doesn't work? Do you get any exception or seeing incorrect output?

Comment: @Shiva I dont get any json output, whereas I get it using urllib

Comment: `req2.json` instead of `req2.text`?

Comment: @Shiva No still doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're sending the wrong type of request. You're sending a GET request, but you need to send a POST, with `requests.post`.

Second, passing a dict as `data` will form-encode the data rather than JSON-encoding it. If you want to use JSON in your request body, use the `json` argument, not `data`:

```
requests.post(url=..., json=d)
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't noticed the escape of quotes in quoestion details. He is passing the json formatted string. You solution is better. However, He can also use `data=json.dumps(dict)` along with `method="POST"`

Answer (score 1):

Reference Link: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/

You can use requests module of python like so

```
import requests
Req = requests.request(
                        method     = "GET", # or "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH" etcetera
                        url        = "http(s)://*", 
                        params     = {"key": "value"}, # IF GET Request  (Optional)
                        data       = {"key": "value"}, # IF POST Request (Optional)
                        headers    = {"header_name": "header_value"}    # (Optional)
)
print Req.content
```

You can surround the code with try::catch block like below to catch any exception thrown by requests module

```
try:
    # requests.request(** Arguments)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print e
```

For full argument list, please check reference link.

Comment: Try with one extra argument, that is `verify=False`. It looks like the target site SSL/TLS certificate is expired.

Comment: Also, Add one more argument `stream=False` along with `verify=False`